# error on multiple data updates that belong to two entities in laravel

Tags: laravel

error on multiple data updates that belong to two entities all data is updated but child table in emp_id is only first insert in all columns. database image attached.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $announcement = Announcement::find($id);
            $dates = explode(' to ' ,$request->date);
            $announcement->title = $request->title;
            $announcement->date = $dates[0];
            $announcement->todate = $dates[1] ?? null;
            $announcement->departments =  implode(',',$request->department);
            $announcement->descriptions = $request->descriptions;
            $announcement->update();
            if($request->employees){
                foreach ($request->employees as $index => $emp_id) {
                 $announcement->announceduser()->where('announcement_id',$announcement->id)->update([
                        'emp_id' => $request->employees[$index]
                    ]);
                }
            }
            return redirect()->route('announcement.index')->with('success', 'Announcement Updated!!');
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IZFd.png)

it is only update first emp_id in all table

Comment: what are you receiving  in this (array or list or) '$request->employees'

Comment: This is difficult and frustrating to read.
Please use punctuation and write clear, complete sentences.

Comment: i recived array of option list show screenshot below

https://ibb.co/1q6VnqR